# Connect to MySQL from Excel

Tags: mysql, excel

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using the 'From SQL Server' option in Excel. I gave the connection details: `Server address`, `username` and `password`, but the connection doesn't get through. Should I make any changes on the server side to make this connection possible?

Thanks for any help you might provide.

[image]

Comment: Don't know why this question is closed. How could I write queries without establishing a successful connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/) is a specific RDBMS product from Microsoft; that is, it is a competing product to MySQL.  You want to use "From Microsoft Query", provided that you have the [MySQL ODBC Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) installed.