# I cant see my mysql database button in excel

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc

I cant see "From mysql databases" button in Get data tab in excel, and just can see Microsoft databases such as Sql-server, Access, SSAS ...and unfortunately Im not be allowed to post the image here,
does anybody know the solution?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15829753/18667225

Comment: Hi Markus, i checked it out but my question is a little diffrent from that

Comment: Please try to explain what is different in your case. Perhaps someone can help if you share more information.

Comment: Im using Excel 2019/2021 version and when i go to  "Data/Get data/From database" in excel tab, mysql button is hidden there and dosent show. It would be good if i can send a photo to clear that enough, if you suggest somewhere i will try it.

Comment: Did you install the MySQL ODBC Driver as suggested in the answer I have linked above?

Comment: Yes, i did... May i send the photo to your email or somewhere else?

Comment: I am not the expert for this issue. There may be others that can help. I just googled for you for existing questions and answers. And as you are new to SO I'm trying to help you to write the question in a way that others may be able to answer. Any parts of your question have to be posted here on SO. You can upload a screenshout in your question if it helps to understand what you are asking. You should black out personal or secret data, of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Markus, I try it out and tell the result

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Hi Marcus, unfortunatelly i couldnt use it and nither find out as well...thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the MySQL Driver from this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15829753/18667225) I can add a new ODBC data source and am able to select the driver.

`Data` -> `From Other Sources` (last one in drop down) -> `From Microsoft Query`

There select `New Data Source` and press `Ok`. In the form you can define a new data source, select the mysql driver etc.